# Why do entries in a matrix not change after a for loop?

Tags: r

I'm trying to do programming in R.

```
p_1_testing <- seq(from = 0.92, to = 1, by = 0.001)
testing_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = 1000-52, ncol = length(p_1_testing))
for (i in 53:1000) {
  cr_left_testing <- qbinom(0.025, i, 0.82)
  cr_right_testing <- qbinom(0.975, i, 0.82)
  for (j in 1:length(p_1_testing)) {
    testing_matrix[i-52, j] <- pbinom(cr_left_testing-1, i, p_1[j]) + 
    (1-pbinom(cr_right_testing, i, p_1[j]))
  }
}
```

It gives the output below.

```
> testing_matrix
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
  [1,] 0.9999982   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
  [2,] 1.0000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
  [3,] 1.0000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
  [4,] 1.0000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
  [5,] 1.0000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
  [6,] 1.0000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
  [7,] 1.0000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
  [8,] 0.9999999   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
  [9,] 0.9999999   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [10,] 1.0000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [11,] 1.0000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [12,] 1.0000000   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
        [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19]
  [1,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  [2,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  [3,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  [4,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  [5,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  [6,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  [7,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  [8,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  [9,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [10,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [11,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [12,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

It goes on like this and at last

```
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 936 rows ]
```

But I don't know why it gives NA for almost all of the entries and even the [1, ] entries are not the answer that I wanted...

For example, I wanted my code having done like below

```
> qbinom(0.025, 53, 0.82)
[1] 38
> qbinom(0.975, 53, 0.82)
[1] 49
> pbinom(37, 53, 0.921) + (1-pbinom(49, 53, 0.921))
[1] 0.3887079
> pbinom(37, 53, 0.92) + (1-pbinom(49, 53, 0.92))
[1] 0.3785474
```

So, for example, what I expected for my code to do was to give testing_matrix[1, 1] as 0.3785474 and testing_matrix[1,2] as 0.3887079.

Why does my code not work? Help me please! Thank you!

Comment: Using your example, the p_1 object is missing

Comment: @Leo Brueggeman thank you so much!